# Qt -- program that uses SQLite crashes

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt-creator, qsqldatabase

I have an application that uses SQLite via Qt libraries (I mean QSqlDatabase). When I run this application from Qt Creator (both in Debug and Release configurations), all works as expected, but when I trying to start an application via .exe file manually, it crashes right after SQLite database operations. I already have "sqldrivers" directory with "qsqlite.dll" file right next to the executable. There's no exception, because I already have a try-catch block around the function that works with SQLite.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

I'm using Qt5 and MSVC-11.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you placed the SQLite database file alongside your exe?

Comment: I have the hardcoded path inside my program. Also I noticed that QSqlDatabase::drivers functions doesn't return anything in case of manually launch of .exe file

Comment: Do you have "Qt5sql.dll" alongside your exe and "qsqlite.dll" inside "sqldrivers" folder?

Comment: @FrozenHeart when the list that `QSqlDatabase::drivers()` returns is empty then the loading of the libraries failed for some reason.

Comment: @Zaiborg Yep, but I can't understand the reason

Comment: when i had problems like this while deploying applications it was basically allways that some dll was incompatible or missing in the deployed file struct

Answer (score 0):

It crashes ... due what? (access violation, assertion)

you can add some logging to see how far your code executes before refusing its job. using `QTextStream`, a redirected `qDebug()`, `std::ofstream` or even a `fprintf()` call will do.

btw Qt does not use exceptions due compatibility to some platforms ...

Comment: It crashes right after QSqlDatabase::addDatabase function call. There is no messages / standard Windows message boxes / etc

Comment: [Please don't abuse `code formatting`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/349538)